# Redirecting to view from HttpPost method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a page called `Catalogs` which takes an Id as a default parameter, there is an `Add Catalog` button on the page which redirects the user to a new page to create a brand new catalog.

This method handles that logic, This method was originally a `JsonResult` method which I am trying to repurpose.:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CreateCatalog(NewCatalogViewModel data)
        {
            var newCatalog = new Catalog
            {
                RelationshipId = data.RelationshipId,
                Name = data.CatalogName,
                OutboundProcessorID = data.OutboundProcessorID,
                Enabled = true,
                Aggregate = data.IsAggregate
            };
            pdbUOW.Catalog.Insert(newCatalog);
            pdbUOW.Save();

            InsertDefaultCatalog(data, newCatalog);


            return CatalogConfig(newCatalog.Id); //Redirect should happen here
        }
```

I would like to redirect the user back to the catalog page passing in the newly created catalog Id as part of the redirect.

```
public ActionResult CatalogConfig(int? id)
        {  return View(); }
```

I have looked at multiple answers on SO but I'm having trouble finding one that applies to what I am trying to do.

While tracing the code I can see that my `CatalogConfig` action result is indeed called, but it doesn't render the view.  What piece am I missing here. I know it has something to do with using `POST` which I need to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way that I found to accomplish the above was, based on success pass back whatever data I want to my view to which you redirect.

```
if (self.CatalogName()) {
                if (confirm("Are you sure you want to create a catalog with the following name?\n" +
                    "Catalog Name: " + self.CatalogName())) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/pdb/PDBConfig/CreateCatalog/',
                        type: 'POST',
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        data: data,
                        success: function (status) {
                            if (status.error) { alert(status.error); }
                            else { window.location.href = "/pdb/PDBConfig/CatalogConfig/" + status; }//Pass back the status containing the url id
                        }
                    });
                }
            } else {
                toastr.warning("You must enter a name for your catalog.");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just redirect to the action, if its in the same Controller, do like this:

**EDIT:**

Return the same `CreateCatalog` passing the model that you just saved:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateCatalog(NewCatalogViewModel data)
{
    var newCatalog = new Catalog
    {
        RelationshipId = data.RelationshipId,
        Name = data.CatalogName,
        OutboundProcessorID = data.OutboundProcessorID,
        Enabled = true,
        Aggregate = data.IsAggregate
    };
    pdbUOW.Catalog.Insert(newCatalog);
    pdbUOW.Save();

    InsertDefaultCatalog(data, newCatalog);


    return View(newCatalog);
}
```

This will show your `CreateCatalog View` with all information about the new model.

Comment: I tried this and it just gets the raw HTML and dumps it onto the page in an alert. Same as the suggestion below.

Comment: This will not have any of the markup or logic found on my `CatalogConfig` page.  I am not sure how this would accomplish what I am trying to do.  I think the issue is that I do not have a view called `CreateCatalog`, this was originally a `JsonResult` method but i'm trying to repurpose it to redirect.  I could not figure out how to redirect from a jsonmethod so i changed the method type.

Comment: I ended up handling the redirect from my ajax call.